# command.ExecuteReader() throwing an exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have a database named `DbTest` and a table named `user`. It is throwing an exception in the line `cmd.ExecuteReader();`

The exception message says:

> There is an error parsing the query

What should I do?

```
conString = Properties.Settings.Default.DbTestConnectionString;
con = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM user", con);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is quite vague if you ask me. The problem lies in the use of the name `user` for your table. `user` is preserved keyword and it can't be used without proper escaping.

Escape `user` with brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM [user]
```

Comment: I tried , but it told me to come back after 15 minutes,that's why.Anyway,thanks.